# Finding the height of the line spacing

Tags: android, text, textview, paint, font-size

I have the following code to find the screen dimensions calculate how much text fits on the screen.

Now I need to know how many lines fit on the screen.  I have the size of the text from the ascent to the descent. I need to know the height of the line spacing. getFontSpacing also gives the value from the ascent to the descent.

Does anyone know if there is a way of finding the line spacing's value?

```
    //Code for Getting screen Dimensions
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;

    //Breaking Text When Width Is Filled
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setTextSize(60);
    int textNum = p.breakText(sText, 0, 20, forOrBack, width, null);

    //Working Out How Many Lines Can Be Entered In The Screen
    float fHeight = p.descent() - p.ascent();
    int tHeight = (int) fHeight;
    int numLines = height/tHeight;
```

Answer (score 3):

The following will return the recommended line spacing

```
textView.getPaint().getFontSpacing()
```

you can get the height of you text several ways. I prefer paint's getTextBounds method and just add the two values together

Answer (score 3):

For line spacing use textView.getLineHeight();

reference : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getLineHeight()

Answer (score 2):

```
Paint.FontMetrics fm = paint.getFontMetrics();
float fullHeight = fm.top - fm.bottom;
```

As far as I remember, fm.bottom < 0, therefore by subtracting you actually get

```
Math.abs(fm.top) + Math.abs(fm.bottom)
```

This value is bigger than ascent-descent, and, I guess, it is the actual line size.

You may consider using TextView.getLineHeight() after setting TextSize and preferebly after layout is complete
(e.g in OnWindowFocusChanged).

Comment: True, in this way i got a larger number although still it isn't the actual value of the text height + the spacing.

Comment: About the setLineSpacing() option, do you know if the line spacing height is affected by the text size, meaning will it change if text size changes and if so is there a ratio to the change in the line spacing height.

Comment: I need to know this information before the layout is complete, as it is needed to complete the layout.

Comment: In my case fm.top was the negative value, and fm.bottom the positive one. Which makes sense since top is "The maximum distance above the baseline for the tallest glyph in the font at a given text size", therefore in the negative direction of the y axis.